# MATLAB How did I make this loop, infinite + also how to shorten i = i + 1?

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop, infinite

I thought this would be a simple iteration but apparently not, I keep seeing the numbers running up the screen and `b = 425.0000` ... which should end my while loop but I have fluffed up royally!

```
temp = 85;
b = 85;
cntr = 0;

while b < 425
  temp = temp * 0.8
  b = b + temp
  cntr = cntr + 1
end;
cntr
```

Also in the above I have `cntr = cntr + 1` but in other languages I could shorten this to `cntr++` or `cntr+=1` how can I do this in MATLAB?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your condition should probably test whether the current value of b is close to the value of 425 up to a certain number of significant digits. you can do this as so:

```
temp = 85; 
b = 85; 
cntr = 0; 

while b < (425 - 0.0001)   #<--- however many significant digits you need.
  temp = temp * 0.8; 
  b = b + temp;
  cntr = cntr + 1;
end

cntr
```

The problem is that your while loop is converging on 425, but never quite getting there.

Comment: Thanks alot, even more explanation ^_^

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `b` converges to 425 but doesn't actually reach 425. `b` is something like 424.9999999999 which when displayed is rounded to 425.

There are no `++` or `+=` operators in Matlab as far as i know.

Comment: Thanks on the `++` and `+=` and any tips on how to fix the 424.99r prob?

Answer (score 1):

You're not printing enough decimal places to demostrate the problem, try running the following:

```
temp = 85; 
b = 85; 
cntr = 0; 

while ( b < 425 ) && ( cntr < 300 )
  temp = temp * 0.8; 
  b = b + temp;
  cntr = cntr + 1;
  fprintf( 1, '%.20f\t%.20f\t%d\n', temp, b, cntr );
end
```

You'll see that `b` never reaches 425, by the time its value is `424.99999999999983` the value of `temp` is `0` and so `b` never increments any further.

MATLAB doesn't implement any increment / decrement operators.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB has no equivalent of pre- and post- increment operators.

Comment: i still think it's such a shame they haven't added that to the language. It can really tidy up code where you want to index and increment in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the limit of your expression is 425, meaning it never actually reaches that value. You'll have to edit your code somehow to account for this.

Also, there is [no such increment operator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/154981).